# Linq query: MAX in WHERE

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have a long query that returns

```
Item {
    DateTime entryDate
    .....
}
```

I like to combine the result of this query with another table

```
Value {
    DateTime date,
    double value
}
```

such that if entryDate >= CUTOFF, then take the value on CUTOFF, else take the value on entryDate.  In other words, I'd want to achieve:

```
 SELECT Item.*, Value.value WHERE
 MIN( Item.entryDate, CUTOFF ) == Value.date
```

Excuse my syntax, but that's the idea.

EDIT: After some trial and error, I came up with this linq-to-sql query:

```
from iValue in Values
join iItem in ... (long query)
let targetDate = iItem.EntryDate > CUTOFF ? iItem.EntryDate : CUTOFF
where iValue.Date == targetDate
select new
{
    iItem,
    targetDate,
    iValue    
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What LINQ provider are you using? LINQ to SQL? LINQ to Entities? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

```
yourLongQuery.Where(y => y.Item.entryDate == Value.date || CUTOFF == Value.date)
             .Select(x => new { 
                              entrydate = (x.Item.entryDate < CUTOFF ? x.Item.entryDate : CUTOFF), 
                              /*rest of x.Item properties here */ , 
                              x.Value.date, 
                              x.Value.value
                              });
```

Filter the query, Combine the two items into one item and modify the first item

Comment: Why is there a `Where` statement?

Comment: the long query Item returns Item. How does it join with Value? 'y.Item.entryDate == Value.date' - Value is not in the scope?

Comment: @Candy sorry misunderstood your original question

Answer (score 0):

> such that if entryDate >= CUTOFF, then take the value on CUTOFF, else
>   take the value on entryDate. In other words, I'd want to achieve:
>   SELECT Item.*, Value.value WHERE  MAX( Item.entryDate, CUTOFF ) ==
>   Value.date

This is contradictory - `if entryDate >= CUTOFF then take the value on CUTOFF` imples that you want `MIN(Item.entryDate, CUTOFF)`, not `MAX`.

Having said that, you just want to select the value.Value that matches each item of your query. Each item should look up the relevant value which matches your MAX (or, I believe, MIN) statement.

```
query.Select(item =>
{
    var matchingValue = Values.Single(v => 
        v.date == Min(item.entryDate, CUTOFF));
    return new { item, matchingValue.value };
});
```

This will return an IQueryable of anonymous `{ Item, double }` objects.

---

If you require this to be a executed as a single SQL statement you'll need to do some refactoring. A good start is to swap `matchingValue` into a single statement.

```
query.Select(item => new { item, context.Values.Single(v => 
    v.date == Min(item.entryDate, CUTOFF)).value });
```

I don't have a Visual Studio in front of me to confirm, but I am not sure that the `Math.Min` function is mapped in LINQ-to-SQL. Let's assume it's not.

```
query.Select(item => new { item, context.Values.Single(v => 
    v.date == (item.entryDate < CUTOFF ? item.entryDate : CUTOFF)).value });
```

I believe that will resolve to a single query if you execute it with a `.ToList()` but can't confirm until I have some tools in front of me. Test it with SQL profiler to be sure.

Comment: does this get translated into one giant SQL?

Comment: You could change it to be one 'giant SQL' if you wanted, but is that a requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you've returned your data from your `Item` query and that the `Value` table is relatively small then this is a nice way to go:

```
var lookup = values.ToLookup(v => v.date, v => v.value);

var query =
    from i in items
    let c = i.entryDate < CUTOFF ? i.entryDate : CUTOFF
    let v = lookup[c].FirstOrDefault()
    select new
    {
        Item = i,
        Value = v,
    };
```

The `ToLookup` extension is very useful and often overlooked.

Comment: ToLookup can be very useful for hashing large datasets.

Comment: I'd prefer a SQL join than a lookup.  The Value table is huge and grows everyday.